# why in p:chart Donut demo the value "10" for the outer graph is not present in the second chart?

Tags: jsf, primefaces

why in http://www.primefaces.org/showcase/ui/chart/donut.xhtml the value "10" for the outer graph is not present in the second chart?

Comment: please only use the java tag when you have questions about the core java language.

Comment: removed the java tag again (second time, it is not java-se related)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In the second chart a slice margin is defined to 5 degrees in this line:

```
donutModel2.setSliceMargin(5);
```

It means each segment will reduce its length by 5 degrees, and it is enough for hidding the little 10 units segment. If you increase the segment length up to 11 then you will start to see the segment.

So if you expect low values in your data then set the slice margin to none or a low number.

I have made the calculations and yes, the length for a 5 degrees arc is a little bit longer than the length for a 10 units arc in a circumference of 760 units, so the shape is hidden.